# Target the width of the window fixed max-width="360px"

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-modal

I work on a web page and I want when I narrowed the page (by the square button to the right of the page close to closing page cross), the reduced page is reduced by a width-max = 360px, ie its minimum length = 360px; how I have to program this is what you had an example of solving this problem is thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read the help section on how to ask questions.

Comment: google `css media queries`

Answer (score 0):

Use **media queries** for responsive designing. In your case you should write your styles inside a media query for `max-width` of `360px`. Like:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 360px) {

    .my-selector {
         /* styles */
    }

}
```

Learn more about **[Media Queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)**.

Hope this helps!

Comment: i try it also but he not worked.thanks very mutch

Comment: hello here is an example to understand me, here is the link of this site https://www.dnvgl.com when I minimize or the size of the page, it mimimizes the maximum with width 360px I want web page also have the same things

Comment: I also work with localhost in google Chrome.